# I can't Identify this "bug" that seems attached to fresh cut wood

Tags: entomology

I'm a *very* amateur entomologist (I'm actually just an old fat hippie that loves all critters).

I don't have any chops here, but I *swear* I've done my due diligence and tried to figure this out. I'm asking because I'm baffled. (Leg stripes are Arachnid-ish, but thorax is completely wrong ... I just dunno...)

My girlfriend sent me a pic; she swears these things were jumping out of a seasoned firewood pile and by her words "attacking".

Location:  PA Pocono mountains, circa Kunkletown, heavily wooded area.

Now granted, there was a lot of drinking going on, it was "girls weekend out", and there was a hot tub.  I wasn't there; so I cannot actually confirm what really happened... (Of course I *wish* I was there, but ... nevermind)

HOWEVER - here's a pic.  You can't make this up.  Or, at least, I'm not making this up ...

What is this critter?  I think it's "insect" by the leg count I can see.  But edumicate me; this is a new one to me and I'm very intrigued.

Many thanks best!

**On Edit**

Perhaps some sort of "wood cricket" based on rough taxonomy of the leg configuration, and it's penchant for jumping.  Pure speculation.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have it.  gOOgle terms "giant cricket wood tiger stripes" yielded very similar critters:  So-called "Camel, Cave, or Cellar Cricket."

Order *Orthoptera (Ensifera)*, Family *Rhaphidophoridae.*

Genus and Species will be next to impossible unless I can capture one, but obviously one of the North American varieties that like to hang out in damp decaying wood.

From the interwebs:

[image: Camel Cricket]

[image: "Greenhouse" Camel Cricket]